# How can i append process name also while creating a crash dump using windbg

Tags: c++, windbg

I am setting up an automatic crash resolver using windbg. I am able to create a dump with unique name but not able to append the crashed application name in the name of created crash dump. Please suggest some way to do it. 
My registry value looks like

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe" -p %ld -e %ld -g -c  ".dump /j %p /ma  /u C:\Users\satyprak\AppData\Local\CrashDumps.dmp; g; qd"

Comment: `/u` is intended to make the dump file unique so that existing dump files will not be overwritten. I don't see a real benefit in adding the application name. What is the application name? The full path? It will contain invalid characters. The executable name? What if it contains spaces? Get the dumps, independent of the file names and write a small script that analyzes them and sorts them into directories or similar.

Comment: It seems you have knowledge about the `/j` switch. Would you mind answering my question over there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733818/how-to-use-the-j-switch-of-dump ?